# How to wrap content to fit column width in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4">
    Name
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-8">
    <b class="d-block">Here some name</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

When viewing on smaller devices I would like that the column widths have priority and the content within them should wrap. Currently, the columns are displayed under each other.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `col-xs-2` isn't a valid class. Please review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap columns not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683579/bootstrap-columns-not-working-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are gonna have to only write this class: `.col-` and you can also add the `.container` class to the container to get some margin from the both sides if you want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="row container">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-4">
        Name
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 col-md-8">
        <b class="d-block">Here some name</b>
    </div>
</div>
```